# How to change the values of a pie chart to absolute values instead of percentages in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to be able to change the percentages under each of the fruit names to absolute numbers (the respective quantities). I tried changing the 'slice label' but that only added the numbers over the slices which is not the desired result for this case. The link to the sheet depicted below can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NLhCQJRzXupIht37pbMTw5kqqmtfVds2RPBi-_3j998/edit?usp=sharing). If this is not possible I would be willing to accept getting rid of the percentages all together and leaving just the labels.

[image: Incorrect Pie Chart]

Comment: What you think of the current answer? If it's not clear, please add a comment to it, but if's fine consider to accept it.

Answer (score 15):

As of today's version of Google Sheets (on Dec 6, 2019), we can do this to make the values appear:

1. Create your pie chart (assuming you know how)
2. Click in the upper right of the chart, on the 3 dots.  "Chart editor" will appear on the right.
3. Under "Chart editor", there will be "Setup" and "Customize".  Click on "Customize"
4. There should be a selection for "Pie chart".  Select that
5. In "Pie chart", there will be something called "Slice label".  The default value is none but change it to "Value"

The raw numbers should appear in the slices of the pie chart.

[image]

Comment: Using "Value and Percentage", the values wouldn't show for me except for the largest slice. It turned it out that the pie size itself was likely too small to show those numbers. When I made the pie large enough all numbers and percentages would show in all of the slices of the pie.

Answer (score 0):

Pie Charts by definition are divided by numerical proportions which almost always will not be whole numbers. So, There comes the percentages.

Also, If you want percentages to be whole numbers in your example, you could calculate the percentages yourself using the formulae in google sheets, put them in a separate column, and make a pie chart selecting only the percentages column. With this Approach, the rounded off percentages may sum upto more than 100. So, we need to adjust it manually in another column as you desire and take care that they add up to 100.

Another thing you could do to hide the percentages is to put your label somewhere on the sides or top or bottom. Go to Customize --> Legend --> position --> adjust.

Also, I have adjusted your graph and columns to show you that it can be done. but there are some shortcomings to these approaches like doing something manually and stuff.

[image: your graph that i adjusted if you dont mind]