# Google Sheets Pie Chart - Display Actual Value Below Label, not in pie chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I know I can get the actual value to show up in the pie chart, i.e. on the slice. However I want the percentage in the pie chart (which I can get to show up) since it is more likely to fit in a slice and the actual value underneath the label. However no matter what I do I can't get anything besides the respective percentage to show up underneath each slice's label. Help!

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question as asked, but for those trying to determine how to display the values on the pie chart slices, the accepted answer here was helpful for me: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132450/how-to-change-the-values-of-a-pie-chart-to-absolute-values-instead-of-percentage