# Showing rounded integer values in a Pie Chart in Google Sheets without decimals (Pie Chart - Slicing Label does not work)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

The proposed solution for the general question has been already asked here: [How to change the values of a pie chart to absolute values instead of percentages in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132450/how-to-change-the-values-of-a-pie-chart-to-absolute-values-instead-of-percentage)

But it doesn't work for me because the value is only shown in 1 of the slices:

[image: screenshot value shown in only 1 slice]

I thought that a solution may be to change the data to currency to show 2 decimals only, but it fixes nothing (the same is being shown):

[image: data format changed to currency to show 2 decimals only]

I believe that's the only way to show the data on a Pie Chart currently:

1. Am I right? Is that the only why?
2. If so: how to show it in all slices when the number has decimals?

Answer (score 0):

Use formulas to create a copy of the data table where you use `round()` to truncate the numbers to two decimal places. Then make the data range of the chart point to the new table.